# Corrupted flash drive after loose USB connection interrupted Linux Mint installation

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting, format

I was installing (at the stage of "copying files...") Linux Mint from a SD card with uncompressed .iso file in a USB Flash drive (it already had installed an old version of LM) when the current went off.
I couldn't install it again.

gParted does not load drives if the flash drive is already installed. I have to remove it and then plug the drive. Then it loads the device, does not show partition sde1 and all options are greyed but options
1) Device -> Create Partition.
2) Device -> Attempt data rescue
3) Format -> ext4 selected but got held despite "it might take a long time"

I tried format it in Mac and Windows unsuccessfully (as FAT32).

*At Ubuntu 18.04*

`dmesg`
[Summary output](https://pastebin.com/ice9C37r)

```
sudo lsblk -f /dev/sde
```

```
[sudo] password for user: 
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sde    iso9660 Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 64-bit 2019-12-13-16-58-44-00               
└─sde1 ext4    Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 64-bit 0937a8f9-54d3-4705-ba68-73cb4e6bedeb
```

```
sudo fsck -p /dev/sde1    
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1    
/dev/sde1: recovering journal
```

hanged up for several hours

```
sudo lsblk -m /dev/sde
```

```
NAME    SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sde    29,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sde1 29,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

`sudo mount /dev/sde1 /mnt` doesn't work

```
 lsusb -v
```

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05dc:a83a Lexar Media, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

I installed mksub. Tried  options "restore to a standtard storage device" and "wipe a device" a but always the procedure got held for a long time

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde bs=1M count=40` and any of dd variations get held

Comment: Do you need to recover any data from the USB drive? If not, it's time to get a new one. They do die sometimes.

Comment: I don't need to recover any data.  I installed Linux Mint on it 2 years ago but I used 3 times for a very short time during this period

Comment: It isn't clear to me if you meant that gParted option "1) Device -> Create Partition" is available because "but" means "except" in that sentence. If it is, then that's the option to choose.

Comment: See that the partition sde1 is already created `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sde` as ext4 format. That option to Create Partition only has MSDOS and other non usual formats.  I had tried that but also gparted freezed

Comment: Yes, it's not worth insisting if there's no simple solution.  Actually the problem was a faulty USB connection on a laptop: one small movement and ...

Comment: Oh. I thought "when the current went off" meant a mains electricity power failure. You will need to get the USB socket fixed so that it doesn't destroy more USB devices. It could be as simple as getting it soldered back on properly: [Faulty USB ports, fixes?](https://superuser.com/q/933349/272824)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [GNOME Disk Utility](https://linuxhint.com/gnome_disk_utility/) https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks which has been able to fix flash drives [gparted](https://gparted.org/) could not.

Comment: I forgot I had Disks installed.  It seems that there's no way to fix that. Tried Fix and now Format.  This device turns on a blue light when it is accessed.  This happens some seconds, then.... darkness!

Comment: Speaking of darkness, you _could_ try using DiskPart in a Windows Command Prompt. https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/how-to-format-ssd.html  (instructions for SSD also work in this instance for USB flash drive). Again it has fixed _some_ misbehaving USB flash drives _sometimes_.

Comment: Also no way. I tried some options like Format, Delete partition, Wipe... After a second "operation successful" but it is not

Comment: As Doctor McCoy would say, "It's dead."